# Django conditionally defined model field in abstract model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've got an abstract model in my project that I want to use to define a field by default on concrete subclasses, but also to allow that field to be redefined as something other than the default dynamically.  All of this works right now:

```
class classproperty(object):
    """
    Decorator for making class properties
    """
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, owner_self, owner_cls):
        return self.fget(owner_cls)

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True

    @classproperty
    def _special_attribute_field(self):
        return getattr(self, '_bm_special_attribute_field', 'default')

    @property
    def bm_special_attribute(self):
        return getattr(self, self._special_attribute_field)
```

...and then there are a bunch of methods that use the latter two functions to figure out which field to access.

The problem is that right now, classes inheriting from `BaseModel` have to define the `default` field explicitly, even if they don't use `_bm_special_attribute_field` to specify something other than the default.  What I'd like to do is programmatically define `default` on concrete submodels *only if* those models don't use `_bm_special_attribute_field` to change it to something else, in which case, they should bring their own field.  Is there a way to do this, perhaps with metaclasses?  The key thing being that it has to not muck up the Django machinery.